# Trying to skip spaces in JavaCC

Tags: regex, parsing, lexical-analysis, javacc

I am writing a lexical analyzer and parser using the Java Compiler Compiler, and I have a problem with SKIP not working on spaces. Newlines, tabs, and comments are skipped just fine, but spaces are not. I know that SKIP doesn't work inside tokens, but I don't understand why I am only having this problem with spaces and not with anything else I have tried to skip.

This is what my SKIP specification looks like:

```
SKIP: {
< " " | "\t" | "\r" | "\n" | "\r\n" > //White space
| <"//" (~["\n","\r"])* ("\n"|"\r"|"\r\n") > //Single-line comments
| <"/*"(~["/"])*  "*""/" > //Multi-line comments
}
```

Then, later on, I have various tokens. Below are a few of them for examples.

```
<DEFAULT> TOKEN : { 
  < COMMAND : "list" > : IN_LIST_COMMAND
| < ID : (["A"-"Z","a"-"z"])+(["A"-"Z","a"-"z","0"-"9"])* >
| < NUMBER : (["0"-"9"])+ > 
...
```

These work just as I would like, except for when there is a space directly after one of them. For instance, if I tried to give

```
list [
```

to the parser, it would give me an TokenManagerError because "list" has a space following it.

**Note:** I have read through every scrap of documentation on JavaCC I can find, both from the main JavaCC website and from other sources. I have also searched for similar questions on StackOverflow and other sites, and found nothing that answers my question.

Comment: What is the error message?  Your first version should work.  Perhaps there is a lexical rule that you haven't shown us that overriding the rule for skipping white spaces.  The file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15705830/MyNewGrammar.jj shows that the rules you have shown will work correctly.

Comment: Well, your file DOES work... Here are links to my jj file and the sample input I use to test it: [test](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwaq5vqjl0h9282/ParseTestWordless.txt) [jj file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttkdjpusodn41lg/Wordless1.jj) Here the problem occurs with the "list" command, in line 6 and column 42 of the sample input. I have removed the optional space from the COMMAND token in the default lexical state.

Comment: Looking at your file, I can see you are using multiple lexical states. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the SKIP production only applies in the `DEFAULT` state. After the keyword "list" the lexer switches to another state. From the JavaCC documentation of the JavaCC Grammar File, we see

> There is a standard lexical state called "DEFAULT". If the lexical
>   state list is omitted, the regular expression production applies to
>   the lexical state "DEFAULT".

The fix is to specify that the production applies in all lexical states. This is done by writing

```
<*> SKIP: {
  < " " | "\t" | "\r" | "\n" | "\r\n" >
| <"//" (~["\n","\r"])* ("\n"|"\r"|"\r\n") >
| <"/*"(~["/"])*  "*""/" >
}
```

which means that the regular expression production applies in all states.

Comment: By the way the syntax for multiline comments is very odd.  For example it will not accept `/* I am /not/ a comment*/`. Read the FAQ for the correct way to do multiline comments. In your case you will either need to deal with such comments separately for each state, or you will need to store the state the lexer was in at the start of the comment and switch back at the end of the comment.

Comment: Thank you...your answer was very helpful! You are right that I should have mentioned lexical states in my original question, so I'm glad you went ahead and added it. I will also take a look at the multiline comments. I wrote that part late at night after I had exhausted most of my thinking ability on other things, and intended it as a sort of placeholder until I worked on it more seriously.